# How do I join a new network on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I'm accepted to a college, and I want to join its network. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click to the Account menu on the top-right, and go to Account Settings, and there is a Networks tab.  You can find networks to join there, and in your case, you will need to provide an email from your school (@yourschool.edu), where you will receive a confirmation email.

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be .edu though, it just needs to be a valid school email address.